# How to return from a thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying use tow thread,form the first get the input and the second process the input.
put the problem I can not found how to return a value from a thread without using callback
an callback does not act like a thread (I think) so any good idea how to do that and thank.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread() {
  public void input() {
    while (true) {
      while (true) {
      /*
       *  get input using Scanner
       */
      }
    }
  }
};

t1.start();
Thread t2 = new Thread() {
  public void input() {
    while (true) {
      while (true) {
      /* get input form above than
       * swith something or do something
       */
      }
    }
  }
};

t2.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a shared BlockingQueue. The first thread (producer) adds the inputs to the queue, and the second one (consumer) gets them from the queue. A BlockingQueue, as its name indicates, is blocking. So the consumer getting the next element from the queue will block until the queue actually contains an element.

Answer (score 0):

Your second thread should raise an event when it has something available for the first thread.  When creating the second thread, have the first thread add itself as a listener, then the second thread uses that to signal the event.

This talks about swing but you can use generic events and listeners for anything.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/

Answer (score 0):

If you only have one thread you may want to use a java.util.concurrent.FutureTask (provided you use Java 1.5 or later).

Answer (score 0):

the blocking queue is the design of choice in such scenarios

Spawn your producer threads and let them insert their data into the queue. Another thread (or the main thread), the consumer, will "spin-lock" watching for data on the queue: as soon as some data arrives, the consumer will grab it and use it.

So your threads "returns" data by inserting it into this common data structure (the queue).

Don't forget to protect your queue using a mutex (it's a critical section) or multiple threads could use (read/write) the queue data structure at the same time causing all sort of weird behaviors, a plain SIGSEGV signal if you are lucky :-)